Ragged Tensor as an output from Tensorflow serving
We use tensorflow serving to serve models in production. We have a use case where the output of the model is a ragged tensor.
To see if the tensorflow serving supports ragged tensor as output, we created this toy example.
tensorflow version 2.14.1
import tensorflow as tf

# Initiate the model
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), ragged=True, name='input_1')
output = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x + 1, dtype=tf.float32)(inputs)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=output)

model.compile()

# Serialise/Deserialise to the format the inferoo expects
model.save("./my_model/1", save_format="tf")
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./my_model/1")


# Make predictions with ragged tensors
x = tf.ragged.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]], dtype=tf.float32)
out = model.predict([x])
print(out)
tf.debugging.assert_equal(out, tf.ragged.constant([[2, 3, 4], [5, 6]], dtype=tf.float32))
print("All good!")

We save the model to a local disk and then load the model via tensorflow serving.
I used [saved_model_cli][1] to inspect model signatures.
The model output has datatype DT_INVALID, I guess the tensorflow serving will fail to load this model.
user@MR26DF61QG ~ % saved_model_cli show --dir /Users/user/ragged_tensor/my_model/1 --all

MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['__saved_model_init_op']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['__saved_model_init_op'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INVALID
        shape: unknown_rank
        name: NoOp
  Method name is:

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['args_0'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1)
        name: serving_default_args_0:0
    inputs['args_0_1'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1)
        name: serving_default_args_0_1:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['lambda'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INVALID
        shape: ()
        name:
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
The MetaGraph with tag set ['serve'] contains the following ops: {'StringJoin', 'VarHandleOp', 'ReadVariableOp', 'ShardedFilename', 'Placeholder', 'Select', 'AssignVariableOp', 'Const', 'Pack', 'MergeV2Checkpoints', 'RestoreV2', 'StatefulPartitionedCall', 'NoOp', 'DisableCopyOnRead', 'Identity', 'StaticRegexFullMatch', 'PartitionedCall', 'AddV2', 'SaveV2'}

Concrete Functions:
  Function Name: '__call__'
    Option #1
      Callable with:
        Argument #1
          DType: RaggedTensorSpec
          Value: RaggedTensorSpec(TensorShape([None, None]), tf.float32, 1, tf.int64)
        Argument #2
          DType: bool
          Value: False
        Argument #3
          DType: NoneType
          Value: None
    Option #2
      Callable with:
        Argument #1
          DType: RaggedTensorSpec
          Value: RaggedTensorSpec(TensorShape([None, None]), tf.float32, 1, tf.int64)
        Argument #2
          DType: bool
          Value: True
        Argument #3
          DType: NoneType
          Value: None

  Function Name: '_default_save_signature'
    Option #1
      Callable with:
        Argument #1
          DType: RaggedTensorSpec
          Value: RaggedTensorSpec(TensorShape([None, None]), tf.float32, 1, tf.int64)

  Function Name: 'call_and_return_all_conditional_losses'
    Option #1
      Callable with:
        Argument #1
          DType: RaggedTensorSpec
          Value: RaggedTensorSpec(TensorShape([None, None]), tf.float32, 1, tf.int64)
        Argument #2
          DType: bool
          Value: False
        Argument #3
          DType: NoneType
          Value: None
    Option #2
      Callable with:
        Argument #1
          DType: RaggedTensorSpec
          Value: RaggedTensorSpec(TensorShape([None, None]), tf.float32, 1, tf.int64)
        Argument #2
          DType: bool
          Value: True
        Argument #3
          DType: NoneType
          Value: None
    ```

Does tensorflow serving support ragged tensors as outputs?


  [1]: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#the_savedmodel_format_on_disk

